# Можно ли перед прямым вопросом вместо двоеточия ставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли перед прямым вопросом вместо двоеточия ставить тире? То есть вместо:

> У меня есть только один вопрос: этот кот-обормот, дезертир, когда в бег пустился, начал сам добывать рыбу форель и ягоду черешню засветло есть, что ли?

писать это:

> У меня есть только один вопрос — этот кот-обормот, дезертир, когда в бег пустился, начал сам добывать рыбу форель и ягоду черешню засветло есть, что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правильно:**

(1) ***У меня есть только одИн вопрос (какой именно?)**: этот кот-обормот, дезертир, когда в бег пустился, начал сам добывать рыбу форель и ягоду черешню засветло есть, что ли?*

В предложении есть слово "один", требующее **обязательного** пояснения( на него ставится **ударение)**. Интонационное предупреждение, пояснительная интонация, **подчеркнутая** пауза.

**Сравнить:**

(2) ***У меня и бЫл-то только  один вопрос (какой?)** —  этот кот-обормот, дезертир, когда в бег пустился, начал сам добывать рыбу форель и ягоду черешню засветло есть, что ли?*

Обязательного пояснения **нет**, оно дается в качестве дополнительной информации. **Присоединительная** интонация, пауза **меньше**.